# removing leading zero and hyphen in Postgres

Tags: postgresql

I need to remove leading zeros and hyphens from a column value in Postgresql database, for example:

121-323-025-000  should look like  12132325
060579-0001  =>  605791
482-322-004 => 4823224

timely help will be really appreciated.

Comment: Your logic is inconsistent.  Sometimes you remove all internal zeroes and sometimes you do not.

Answer (score 4):

[Postgresql string functions.](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-string.html)
For more advanced string editing, regular expressions can be very powerful.  Be aware that complex regular expressions may not be considered maintainable by people not familiar with them.

```
CREATE TABLE testdata (id text, expected text);
INSERT INTO testdata (id, expected) VALUES
    ('121-323-025-000', '12132325'),
    ('060579-0001', '605791'),
    ('482-322-004', '4823224');
SELECT id, expected, regexp_replace(id, '(^|-)0*', '', 'g') AS computed
  FROM testdata;
```

[How regexp_replace works.](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-matching.html#FUNCTIONS-POSIX-REGEXP)  In this case we look for the beginning of the string or a hyphen for a place to start matching.  We include any zeros that follow that as part of the match.  Next we replace that match with an empty string.  Finally, the global flag tells us to repeat the search until we reach the end of the string.

Comment: This is exactly I was looking for. Thanks for your help.